# Excel formula to Increment every after X Number of Years

Tags: excel, vba, algorithm

I would like to Add an Increment of One on Every X Year Interval
For Example if X = 3 Then the Following Data should be

```
SG  Last Year
5     2010
4     2014
3     2015
6     2016
```

Would result to

```
Grp Last Year   2016    2017    2018    2019    2020
5     2010       6       6       6       7       8
4     2014       4       5       5       5       6
3     2015       3       3       3       4       4
6     2016       6       6       6       7       7
```

So the First Record the Candidate is in group 5, from 2010, in 2016 I would like to calculate if the candidate has a span of at least 3 years if so, push him to 1 upper group which is 6. The Same Candidate will go through n Number of years and every 3 years (X Number of Years) would increment their group till we reach to 1 and continues with 1 without any increment. Thus is the same example since we increment in 2016, the candidate would have the same group for the next 3 years and only in 2019 would we increment again and so on.

I would like and excel formula or process which I could use for the data set proposed

Comment: How about you try and we help? With 300 rep you should know that *I would like an excel formula* does not work here.

Comment: @MikelisBaltruks for 2016  I used =IF((2016-Last Year)>X-1,Grp+1,Grp). I need to take it forward with the explained. If you think it's so simple for my rep, you have 900+ why don't you help :)

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there.

```
 LY = Last year (that static cell in each row); 
 AY = Active year (the column for which you are calculating),
 G = group (start value),
 PR = previous result (for prev year),
 R = result (what you want to get),
 X = year interval`
```

1. You can use one formula for first year (2016) and another for the rest, so you can use previous value `PR`, not initial group `G`.
2. Obviously `LY` stays constant for the row.
3. `R = IF (( (AY-LY) \ X)==0 , PR+1, PR)` - change when mod is 0.
4. Use #3 formula for all the years except first column (2016).
5. For first column (2016) instead of `PR` you should use `G`.
6. To have a constant cell, you write in form of `$A$1` (for `G`)
7. For constant row you write in form of `C$0` (for `AY`)
8. *Your formula was almost correct. And you need to set the values constant where they need to be.*

Comment: Hope you understand. I can provide an algorithm, but not the actual formula. But you should get through!

Comment: MikelisBaltruks The Algorithm does not return the desired result. For the example given in 2019 the Grp should change to 3 which does not.

Comment: Why not? The `IF` should go through. *If the difference between `Last year` and active year can be divided by 3, than it changes.* That's the algorithm. And why would it change to 3? In which row?

Comment: Since the LY is 2010, so 2016 will change the G from 5 to 4. In 2017 it will not change as the last change was 2016. Thus till 2019 it will change to 3 since 2016+3 = 2019 and in 2020 it will stay as 3

Comment: why from 5 to 4? shouldn't the number go up? And also - isn't it correct? it changes every 3 years - if start 2010, then 2016, 2017, 2018 is 1 up, then '19, '20, '21 is up another.

Comment: Yes you are right, but your proposal changes for 2016,2017 and 2018 and 2019 and going on stays the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121248/discussion-between-mikelis-baltruks-and-szakwani).